# Apostrophes and regular expressions; Cleaning text in R

Tags: r, regex, text, nlp

I working on cleaning a large collection of text. My process thus far is:

- Remove any non-ASCII characters
- Remove URLs
- Remove email addresses
- Correct kerning (i.e., "B A D" becomes "BAD")
- Correct elongated words (i.e., "baaaaaad" becomes "bad")
- Ensure there is a space after every comma
- Replace all numerals and punctuation with a space - except apostrophes
- Remove any term 22 characters or longer (anything this size is likely garbage)
- Remove any single letters that are leftover
- Remove any blank lines

My issue is in the next-to-last step. Originally, my code was:

```
gsub(pattern = "\\b\\S\\b", replacement = "", perl = TRUE)
```

but this wrecked any contractions that were left (that I left in on purpose). Then I tried

```
gsub(pattern = "\\b(\\S^'\\s)\\b", replacement = "", perl = TRUE)
```

but this left a lot of single characters.

Then I realized that I needed to keep three single-letter words: "A", "I", and "O" (either case).

Any suggestions?

Comment: So, what do you need in the end? Remove all single letters (enclosed with word boundaries) but `A`, `I` and `O`? Try `gsub("\\s*\\b(?![AOI])\\p{L}\\b", "", x, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE)`

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate all single-letter terms except A, I, and O (either case). So far, the closest attempt is: `\b[b-hj-np-z]\b` - but this still matches single letters after apostrophes.

Comment: So, if there is a `'` on the left, fail the match, right? Try `gsub("(?i)\\s*\\b(?<!')(?![AOI])\\p{L}\\b", "", x, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: I think this is it - but without the `\\s*` in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
gsub("(?i)\\b(?<!')(?![AOI])\\p{L}\\b", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

*Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching on
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!')` - no `'` is allowed immediately on the left
- `(?![AOI])` - the next char cannot be `A`, `I`, or `O`
- `\p{L}` - any Unicod letter
- `\b` - a word boundary